# Jquery - need to find corresponding cell title when looking at cell value

Tags: jquery, class

When I hover over a tables' cell value.. I need a way to capture the "first columns title" that corresponds to the cell I hovered over. I attached a picture that explains it more clear.
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBqSD.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve]. We don't debug images of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the **[`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)** pseudo-class selector to target the first `td` element, and then to get its title you'll want to make use of the **[`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** attribute.

```
$('tr td:first-child').prop('title');
```